# Export data to csv file using $in

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to export data to csv file using mongo export with some condition with the following command

```
mongoexport --db <db_name> --collection <coll_name> --query "'meta.metaData.fieldName' : {$in : [EZR-2016-21123,EZR-2016-22016, EZR-2016-23420]}}" --fields <field_name> --type=csv --out out_file_name.csv
```

This works fine for other normal query, but when I put $in, it doesn't work.

Comment: Because those would be 'string' arguments and you forgot to quote them.

Comment: *"it doesnt work"* is no appropriate error description. Please provide the error details (**edit** the question accordingly, please no not add the details as a comment).

Answer (score 0):

You need to updated the query to be the following

```
mongoexport --db <db_name> --collection <coll_name> --query "{'meta.metaData.fieldName' : {'$in' : ['EZR-2016-21123', 'EZR-2016-22016', 'EZR-2016-23420']}}" --fields <field_name> --type=csv --out out_file_name.csv
```

- You are missing the starting `{` off your query
- Strings within the `$in` array need to be quoted